# C++ delayed tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to implement a way to schedule a task to be executed at a later time. The interface would be similar to JavaScript's `setTimeout(function, milliseconds)`.

In my application certain resources are owned by a thread. To avoid race conditions they must always be accessed from that same thread. If other threads want to access the resource they must dispatch a task object to the resource thread.

So two problems I need to solve are:

1. dispatch a task to a thread
2. delay the invocation

The first problem is quickly fixed by using a lock-free queue which has the resource thread at the consuming side. (I use TBB's concurrent_bounded_queue.) The second problem however, is not so obvious for me. I can think of two strategies:

1. Start a new thread for each task. This thread will sleep the required delay, then dispatch the task to the concurrent queue.
2. Start only one thread which runs a loop that iterates the scheduled tasks and invokes them if their waiting time has expired.

I've experimented with both approaches and I tend to favor the first because it's simple and reliable, while the second tends to be more prone to subtle bugs. The first approach delegates this to the OS thread scheduler.

However, the first solution does create a lot of short-lived threads, while I usually hear the recommendation to reuse threads.

Comment: there is no guarantee in the second approach of timely excecution.
sometimes you would have to wait for one task to finish before executing the second one. The first approach is better.

Comment: Is the number of threads spawned really going to be that much? Like a few houndred thousand? Remember that sleeping threads consume pretty close to 0 CPU time.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz In my application there won't be many simultaneously scheduled tasks. Usually they will perform an action every N milliseconds. They do this by rescheduling themselves before they die.

Comment: @StackedCrooked how did you finally solved the question?

Comment: @user3887420 I'm currently using a boost::asio::io_service object with deadline_timer.

Answer (score 3):

Manual implementation will be something like below.

```
struct myrunnable {
  uint64_t id_;
  uint64_t stamp_;
  std::function<void()> runnable_;
  uint64_t id() { return id_; }
  uint64_t stamp() { return stamp_; }
  void execute() { if (runnable_) runnable_(); }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<myrunnable> task_t;
// timestamp_cmp_t - a comparator by timestamp + incrementing task id
typedef tbb::concurrent_blocking_queue<task_t> queue_t;
typedef std::priority_queue<task, timestamp_cmp_t> schedule_t;

uint64_t now(); // a wrapper around gettimeofday(), write yourself

queue_t queue; // inbound concurrent blocking queue not bound in size
schedule_t schedule; // priority queue, a scheduler
// queue_t sink; // optional sink concurrent queue if you don't
                 // want to execute tasks in the scheduler thread context

// now() - a wrapper around gettimeofday(), write yourself
for(;;) { // "termination mark" comments below - exit points
  while (!schedule.empty() && schedule.top().stamp() <= now()) {
    task_t task = schedule.pop();
    task .execute();
    // alternatively sink.push(task) to offload scheduler thread
  }

  if (schedule.empty()) {
    task_t task = queue.pop(); // block on the input queue
    if (!task) return; // scheduler termination mark, empty task
    schedule.push(task);
  } else {
    // Here we are driven by our latency/cpu balance requirements
    // in this example we are ultra low latency and are just spinning CPU
    // and on Linux such thread may need extra tuning to perform consistently.
    // To pace it down one can use TBB's sleep_for() or select() system call

    while (schedule.top().stamp() > now()) {
      task_t task;
      if (queue.try_pop(task)) {
        if (!task) return; // scheduler termination mark, empty task
        schedule.push(task);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SigTerm - The comment in the code just above the tight spinning loop clearly states that there are many ways of waiting for data to come, including spinning, nop-based spinning (via tbb::sleep_for), or deep sleep via a system call like select(), which cannot sleep less than 10ms, btw. You should stop seeing world in black and white :)